# Configurações de texto em latex

Tags: formatação, latex

Boa tarde, estou com algumas dúvidas em certas configurações no latex. Vou dividir em partes.

Capa:

1) Como eu faço para colocar um tamanho específico de fonte em determinadas partes? Por exemplo título(`\title{}`) com letra tamanho 40, nome (`\author{}`) com tamanho 20. Preciso criar uma fonte específica?

2)Existe alguma forma de dar mais espaços verticais alem do comando `\\`, por exemplo se eu quiser pular 3 ou 4 linhas.

Texto:

1) Para alterar o tamanho da fonte no texto todo, com exceção da capa, apenas utilizo `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`?

2) Como faço espaçamento duplo?

3) Como defino as dimensões da página? Preciso que o corpo do texto tenha 14cm de largura e 19cm de altura.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma resposta em LaTeX. :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{Teste para o SOPT}
\author{Luiz Carlos Vieira}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\scshape}{(os pirata!)~\thesection}{2cm}{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Este é só um teste.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introdução}

Eis uma resposta dada diretamente em \LaTeX. \smiley{}

\subsection{Pergunta 1}

\begin{quotation}
\noindent\textit
``Como eu faço para colocar um tamanho específico de fonte em determinadas partes? Por exemplo título(\verb!\title{}!) com letra tamanho 40, nome (\verb!\author{}!) com tamanho 20. Preciso criar uma fonte específica?''
\end{quotation}

Use os comandos de tamanho de fonte, como \verb!\small!, ou \verb!\Large!, ou ainda \verb!\LARGE!. Os comandos disponíveis são:

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\verb!\tiny! & \tiny exemplo \\
\hline
\verb!\scriptsize! & \scriptsize exemplo \\
\hline
\verb!\footnotesize! &  \footnotesize exemplo \\
\hline
\verb!\small! & \small exemplo \\
\hline
\verb!\normalsize! & \normalsize exemplo \\
\hline
\verb!\large! & \large exemplo \\
\hline
\verb!\Large! & \Large exemplo \\
\hline
\verb!\LARGE! & \LARGE exemplo \\
\hline
\verb!\huge! & \huge exemplo \\
\hline
\verb!\Huge! & \Huge exemplo \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

Há outras formas também. Para saber mais, veja aqui: \url{https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts}.

Para alterar a fonte de seções reutilizáveis, como é o caso de títulos de seções, subseções, etc, você pode redefinir seus comandos, mas é mais simples usar algum pacote como o ``titlesec''  -- que eu usei aqui para ilustrar com o seguinte comando (que define a fonte como Larga e coloca ``(os pirata!) '' fixo na frente do título):

\begin{verbatim}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\scshape}{(os pirata!)~\thesection}{2cm}{}
\end{verbatim}

Para saber mais sobre o ``titlesec'', leia: \url{https://pt.sharelatex.com/learn/Sections_and_chapters#Customize_chapters_and_sections} e a própria documentação do pacote.

\subsection{Pergunta 2}

\begin{quotation}
\noindent\textit
``Existe alguma forma de dar mais espaços verticais alem do comando \verb!\\!, por exemplo se eu quiser pular 3 ou 4 linhas.''
\end{quotation}

Sim, existe. Várias. Você pode aumentar o espaço da nova linha no próprio comando \verb!\\! fazendo \verb!\\[1cm]!, por exemplo. Assim, o script abaixo:

\begin{verbatim}
Olá mundo!\\[1cm]
Mundo, tá ai?\\[2cm]
Muuuunnndooo?\\[3cm]
Tchau mundo!\\
\end{verbatim}

Resulta em:
\\
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
Olá mundo!\\[1cm]
Mundo, tá ai?\\[2cm]
Muuuunnndooo?\\[3cm]
Tchau mundo!\\
\end{minipage}

Ou você pode usar o comando \verb!\vspace{}\verb! (para espaço vertical, há também o \verb!\hspace{}\verb! para espaço horizontal) informando entre as chaves a dimensão em centímetros, ou em pontos, ou nas diferentes unidades que existem no \LaTeX (saiba mais em \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm}).

\subsection{Pergunta 3}

\begin{quotation}
\noindent\textit
``Para alterar o tamanho da fonte no texto todo, com exceção da capa, apenas utilizo \verb!\documentclass[12pt]{article}\verb!?''
\end{quotation}

Sim, essa é a maneira ideal de fazer isso. Até porque é mais adequado você configurar os itens da capa de forma independente do restante do texto.

\subsection{Pergunta 4}

\begin{quotation}
\noindent\textit
``Como faço espaçamento duplo?''
\end{quotation}

A melhor maneira é utilizar o pacote ``setspace'' adicionando \verb!\usepackage{setspace}\verb! ao preâmbulo. Então, use o comando \verb!\doublespacing\verb! dentro do escopo desejado (pode ser todo o documento, ou pode ser um \textit{environment} do tipo \verb!\begin{...}...\end{...}\verb!).

\subsection{Pergunta 5}

\begin{quotation}
\noindent\textit
``Como defino as dimensões da página? Preciso que o corpo do texto tenha 14cm de largura e 19cm de altura.''
\end{quotation}

Use o pacote ``geometry''. Mais informações aqui: \url{https://pt.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins}. Por exemplo, você pode adicionar o seguinte ao preâmbulo:

\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2cm,%
            left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,%
            footskip=.25cm]{geometry}
\end{verbatim}

\section{Conclusão}

\textit{That's all folks!}

\end{document}
```

Aqui estão imagens do PDF compilado (que também [pode ser baixado do PDFSr](http://pdfsr.com/pdf/teste-para-o-sopt.pdf)):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]